# Silverlight: Why does this work only when in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight **out-of-browser** app which was previously an **in-browser** app.

When it was an in-browser app, this used to work fine:

```
LeftPanelScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((int) double.Parse(verticalOffset));
```

After I made it out-of-browser, it stopped working. It worked only when I wrote it inside Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{ 
     LeftPanelScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((int) double.Parse(verticalOffset));
});
```

Why does it have to be in `BeginInvoke` for it to work?

Comment: One possibility is that there is a race condition at work and the timings changed between the two types of running the code. Dispatching work changes timings again quite a bit. In my opinion the symptoms you see suggest that in neither case the code is probably really "correct", just happen to work better in some cases, and maybe just on your machine.  I don't have a really good tip on how to do it the right way in those situations I'm afraid.